# I want the user to change the password by entering his id and old password and replace the old password with the new one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to reset the password.
In the login model, I have:

```
      public string LoginId { get; set; }

      public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

      public string NewPassword { get; set; }
      public string confpassword { get; set; }
      public int flag { get; set; }
```

and in login table I have:

LoginId as integer and
loginpassword string

In the controller I have:

```
      public ActionResult passwordchange()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult passwordchange([Bind(Include = "LoginId,LoginPassword,NewPassword,confpassword")] login chk)
    {
       login temp = db.Login.Find(chk.LoginId);
if (temp == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "not exist");
   return View(temp);
}
if (temp.LoginPassword.Equals(chk.LoginPassword))
{
      if (chk.NewPassword == chk.confpassword)

    {                   
        chk.LoginPassword = chk.NewPassword;

        TempData["alertMessage"] = "sucess";
```

// tracing upto here is ok but password does not get saved in database table //even whei tried to to do db.save(chk) but comes up with error 
            return RedirectToAction("account", "index");
        }

```
    TempData["alertMessage"] = "error";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Try `db.SaveChanges();` before `return RedirectToAction("account", "index");` - that should save the data in the database

Comment: I already mentioned that i added db.SaveChanges(); but it doesnt get save

Comment: You mentioned `db.save(chk)` - that is not the same as `db.SaveChanges();` - so have you tried SaveChanges too?

Comment: If `db.SaveChanges` doesnt work, then the entity might have been detached and you would need to attach again and set the state to modified

Comment: @Ebrahim, What kind of authentication are you using? Is that forms authentication via .Net Membership class?

Comment: ya u r right, but no use of that ,any way to use sql insert values

Comment: @derloopkat actually am not using membership coz dont know how to use that :/